# How do I find all squads attending all events whose start date is greater than some value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My two models are straightforward:

```
squad.rb
  belongs_to :event

event.rb
  has_many :squads
```

I've got a rake task that generates rankings based on the results of each squad at each event.

I'm in my second year and need to update my rankings script to only pull squads attending events whose start date is greater than 2010-10-30.

I'm sure this a very easy thing to do, but I can't seem to figure it out.

My app is running on 2.3.8 for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`squad.rb`

`named_scope :scope_name, :include => :event, :conditions => [ "events.start_date > ?", YOUR_DATE]`

Then use

`Squad.scope_name`

I hope i didn't any mistakes)

Comment: Nailed it!! I was headed in this direction, but hadn't figured out how to join the events table. Time to hit the ActiveRecord books. Thanks man...I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Squad.all(:joins => :event, :conditions => "events.start_date > '2010-10-30'")
```

or

```
date = "2010-10-30"
Squad.all(:joins => :event, :conditions => ["events.start_date > ?", date])
```